# JQuery prepending data from a form to a table

Tags: jquery

I'd like whatever's written in #tweet to be added to a new row, prepended to the #feed. For some reason, when I submit the form on my browser, a row is created and immediately disappears. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
<head>
    <title>Simple Twitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tweetForm").submit(function(){
                row = $("<tr>");
                var tweet = $(".form-control tweetText").val();
                $("#feed").prepend($("<tr><td>"),tweet,$("</td>"));
            })
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="container" style="width:50%">
    <h1>Twitter</h1>
    <form id="tweetForm" action="" method="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control tweetText" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group float-right">
            <input type="submit" class="tweet btn btn-primary" value="Tweet"> 
        </div>
    </form>

    <table id="feed" class="table timeline">
        <tr>
            <td>I'm having lunch right now</td>
        <tr>
            <td>This is my first Tweet!!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem solved or still present? -> Answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `submit` triggers a page-reload. All changes get lost.
Please try `preventDefault` in the `submit` function:

```
$("#tweetForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    row = $("<tr>");
    var tweet = $(".form-control tweetText").val();
    $("#feed").prepend($("<tr><td>"),tweet,$("</td>"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you can't make a single element by combining multiple jquery elements like you have...

```
.prepend($("<tr><td>"),tweet,$("</td>"));
```

In effect I believe that will create `<tr><td></td></tr>` and then you append the value of `tweet`, and then you're creating something that doesn't make sense... something like this `<tr><td></td></tr>tweet</td>`.

What you probably want to do is create the element, and then populate it...

```
.prepend($("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>").text(tweet)))
```

```js
$(function() {
  var tweet = "hello world";
  $("#feed").prepend($("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>").text(tweet)))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="feed" class="table timeline">
  <tr><td>I'm having lunch right now</td></tr>
  <tr><td>This is my first Tweet!!</td></tr>
</table>
```